# Range input min, max value large integer array sorting getting this error Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, range

I'm working on input type range slider here I trying to scale image on slide move here it is working fine when I use min='0' and max='100'

```js
slider.oninput = function() {
  first.innerHTML = this.value * 200;
}
var imageScale = new Array();
imageScale = [{
  'transform': 'scale(0.7)'
}, {
  'transform': 'scale(0.9)'
}, {
  'transform': 'scale(1.1)'
}, {
  'transform': 'scale(1.3)'
}, {
  'transform': 'scale(1.8)'
}, {
  'transform': 'scale(0.25)'
}];

$(document).on('input change', '#slider', function() { //listen to slider changes
  var v = $(this).val(); //getting slider val

  $("#img").css(imageScale[v]);
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 60px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="range" id="slider" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" />
<span id="first"></span>units
<img src="http://cdn2.stylecraze.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/dahlia-flowers.jpg" id='img' />
```

Now I change min, max to `min="3412" max="341214"` large integer number then image scaling is not working. Maybe this is due to array indexing. can anyone suggest me what I'm doing wrong here guide me in the right direction. Any help will be appreciate

Comment: You only have 6 elements in the array. What sort of output are you expecting when someone moves the slider outside of values 0 to 6?

Comment: @CertainPerformance only 0 to 6 sort. its is working when min=0 and max=100 when i changed to min="3412" max="341214" not working. because this.val(); in a large integer.

Comment: It is *not* working with `min=0 and max=100` - see your snippet, lots of errors get thrown.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Getting this error `jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined` when min,max  large integer value.

Comment: Yes, and it also throws that with small integer values in the above snippet. The only values for which it *doesn't* throw are 0 to 6. What are you expecting when values outside 0-6 are inputted?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I want to scale image only up to 6 moves and then stops.

Comment: In that case, changing the values on `min="3412" max="341214"` would have no effect at all, since the values are far past the range of the array? Is that what you want?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Using these values `min="3412" max="341214"` only i want to achieve image scaling.

Comment: What sort of image scaling? They're far past the range of 0-6 of the array, so would you want the result to be static at the value you've set at index 6? It's not really clear what you're hoping to achieve for the general case

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like all you need to do is call `Math.max` on the value in the input first, so that you can extract from the array *either* the index in the slider *or* the maximum index in the array. That will ensure you get an object in your `v` variable, and you can set the `css`.

For example, with `imageScale` having 6 items, if the user slides to value 3, set the CSS to the object at index 3. If the user slides to value 20, or 100, or 10000, that's outside the range of the array, so you can set the CSS to the object at the highest index in the array - here, that's `[5]`:

```js
slider.oninput = function() {
  first.innerHTML = this.value * 200;
}
var imageScale = [{
  'transform': 'scale(0.7)'
}, {
  'transform': 'scale(0.9)'
}, {
  'transform': 'scale(1.1)'
}, {
  'transform': 'scale(1.3)'
}, {
  'transform': 'scale(1.8)'
}, {
  'transform': 'scale(0.25)'
}];

$(document).on('input change', '#slider', function() { //listen to slider changes
  var v = Math.min($(this).val(), imageScale.length - 1); //getting slider val
  $("#img").css(imageScale[v]);
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 60px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="range" id="slider" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" />
<span id="first"></span>units
<img src="http://cdn2.stylecraze.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/dahlia-flowers.jpg" id='img' />
```

Note that the current code results in out-of-bounds values resulting in a smaller picture - this is because the last item in the `imageScale` array is `'transform': 'scale(0.25)'`, much smaller than all the other items in the array. (If you want the last item to be *larger* than the other items in the array, maybe do something like `'transform': 'scale(2.5)'`)

Comment: Not quite - the first 5 CSS objects *do* get displayed, try moving the slider near the left limit. Since the input range is 0-100, but the array elements are only 0-5, you have to get very close to the left to see the changes, otherwise you'll only see the last element in the array - which is what you wanted, as you said in the comments

Comment: when I change to `min="3412" max="341214"` directly last one is coming.

Comment: As expected, because the ranges are far beyond the values of the array - which you said is what you wanted earlier. You said *yes static only whatever the values I wrote inside array those values only* - and, indeed, when the input range is far higher than the range of the array, the resulting image is static.

Comment: @CertainPerformace I mean static 6 values inside array all have to come. I appreciate your effort.

Comment: But if the slider values are higher than the range of the array, you said you wanted the rendered value to be the item at the end of the array: *I want to scale image only up to 6 moves and then stops.* With such a large input range, because it's so far beyond the range of the array, the only result that will be displayed will be the value at index 5. It looks to be implementing what you're asking for